# How could I disable keybindings when writing Q&A on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> to kill a line from the current point in a shell and all text editors.

When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> in order to delete a line while typing a question or answer on Stack Overflow, I always end up failing on deleting a line. Hence, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> it puts [`enter code here`].

Is there a way to disable keybinding while typing my questions or answers on Stack Overflow or somehow change the keybindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a userscript to do that.

I created one for you which will give Ctrl+K on Stack Overflow the behavior that you are used to: Cut from cursor to end of line (to clipboard, if allowed by browser).

1. Install [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) for your browser
2. Click the Tampermonkey icon in the toolbar and select "Create new script"
3. Paste the script below
4. Click the save button

The script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Cut from cursor instead of creating code block
// @version      0.1
// @description  Cut from cursor on Ctrl+K on Stack Overflow instead of creating code
// @author       CherryDT
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict'

  document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    // If the key in question is Ctrl+K
    if (e.which === 75 && e.ctrlKey) {
      // Prevent Stack Overflow's default behavior
      e.stopImmediatePropagation()

      // If cursor is in a textarea or an input field...
      const field = document.activeElement
      if (field.tagName === 'TEXTAREA' || field.tagName === 'INPUT') {
        // Find the end of the current line
        let lineEnd = field.value.indexOf('\n', field.selectionStart)
        // ...in case there is no newline at the end...
        if (lineEnd === -1) lineEnd = field.value.length
        // ...in case there was a CRLF...
        if (lineEnd > 0 && field.value[lineEnd - 1] === '\r') lineEnd--

        // Select rest of line
        field.setSelectionRange(field.selectionStart, lineEnd)

        // Copy, if possible
        try {
          document.execCommand('copy')
        } catch (e) {
          console.warn('Failed to copy', e)
        }

        // Remove text
        field.setRangeText('', field.selectionStart, field.selectionEnd, 'start')

        // Prevent browser default action
        e.preventDefault()
      }
    }
  }, { capture: true }) // Handle in capture phase to be "faster" than Stack Overflow
})()
```

A few notes:

- If you want to have this behavior on *all* sites and not just Stack Overflow, change the `@match` line from `https://stackoverflow.com/*` to `*://*/*`
- If you don't want to move the cut text to the clipboard but just remove it, delete the `try` block.

Comment: Thank you @CherryDT. Is there any way to apply them into Safari browser as well?

Comment: Yes: https://www.tampermonkey.net/index.php?ext=dhdg&browser=safari

Comment: Ah it is not free under Safari but I think it is worth it

Comment: You can try if the script works the way you want first, by simply copying it into the devtools console on a Stack Overflow page. But then the effect will only last until you navigate to a new page.

Comment: Can I apply the exact code on hackerrank's code editor bottom of the page (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/py-hello-world/problem)?

Comment: Try it... As mentioned in my answer: If you want to have this behavior on _all_ sites and not just Stack Overflow, change the `@match` line from `https://stackoverflow.com/*` to `*://*/*`

Comment: I have tried but seems like `ctrl+k` does not work to delete a line. It is so much pain be unable to use a keybinding that you need the most but cannot use it for 8 hours in this editor.

Comment: OK I see now this is not a regular text field, it's their own syntax-highlighted editor. Sorry this doesn't work then, it would require some additional development specifically for that case.

Comment: Thanks anywayI asked it as a different questions since it requires a different solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62271638/how-to-enable-emacs-keybindings-on-the-online-programming-editors-like-on-hacke

Comment: Would this solution work under https://docs.google.com/ ? I tried it but seems like it does not have any effect